# Deleted file holding on to file descriptor until garbage collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a java service that downloads very large files, does some processing, then deletes them.  I've noticed that the service holds on to the file descriptor until garbage collection runs.  This is a problem because the OS (debian) can't reclaim that space until the file descriptor is released.  How can I force the JVM to reclaim that space after the file object goes out of scope?  I'd prefer to not use `system.gc()`.

To be clear, I've observed this behavior by

1. running `lsof` and seeing the deleted files (marked as `deleted`).  Also `df -h` shows the files taking up space.
2. running `jcmd <pid> GC.run`
3. running `lsof` and no longer seeing the file.  `df -h` shows disk space released.

Here's a simplified version of the Java Code:

```
public void downloadAndProcess() throws IOException {
    File destinationFile = new File("blah");
    s3Client.getObject(
            new GetObjectRequest(bucket, key),
            destinationFile
    );
    // do some processing
    destinationFile.delete();
}
```

Comment: Do you close the files? Either by manually calling close() or by using try-with-resources?

Comment: There is no file descriptor involved in deletion, although there are reports of Windows implementations holding on to resources via `File` until GC.

Comment: If you don't like the answer please comment why. JVM garbage collector gets rid of useless file descriptors(just small integers), but it doesn't have much to do with locking or deleting files.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I don't close the files.  I'm not streaming so there's no way to close.  I've pasted the java code.

Comment: I expect `S3Client.getObject` properly closes the file after it saves the downloaded data. But what do you do with that file before you delete it? What does "`// do some processing`" actually do with the file? I bet it's opening it and not closing it.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou yes, it turned out one of the processing methods wasn't closing out it's InputStream properly!

Comment: And so I guessed right without seeing - the issue was internal, in the code that you  didn't post even though I asked about it. It certainly had nothing to do with "OS garbage collecting" "file descriptors".

Answer (score -1):

"This is a problem because the OS (debian) can't reclaim that space until the file descriptor is released"

That's your problem, that's not correct. The file descriptor is just an integer, every process gets one(and it depends on process, not os-wise). Os will reclaim space in that situation and that's exactly what file descriptors are for(not a pointers to the file bytearray).

If that still bugs you in any way, please post your java code and your shell code, so that it can be clear what's the problem is.

Comment: No, my OS will not reclaim the space until GC happens.  If I issue a `sudo df -h /`, I see the space hasn't been released.

Comment: That's your answer right there. read http://askubuntu.com/questions/280342/why-do-df-and-du-commands-show-different-disk-usage#390301

Comment: That answer is not completely correct because its not file descriptors, its called differently(file descriptor is a process specific small integer of 4 bytes, it does not occupy anything more then 4 bytes - 0x00000003 for your first opened file). But the point this command gives something different then you think it is. You can get that space.(use du command)